# How to detect if a CMake variable is a cache variable?

Tags: cmake

What would be the simplest way in that can be used inside an `if()` to detect whether given CMake variable name is a "cache variable" and not a regular variable?

Consider following example:

```
set(regularVariable "some value")
set(aVariableInCache "some other value" CACHE INTERNAL "")

get_cmake_property(variables VARIABLES)
foreach(variable ${variables})
    if(???)
        ...
    endif()
endforeach()
```

I'm looking for a simple way to distinguish between `regularVariable` and `aVariableInCache` only based on which one is in the CMake cache and which one is just a regular variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think, you can get away with

```
get_property(result CACHE ${variable} PROPERTY TYPE)
```

Empty value for `result` would mean that the variable isn't present in the cache.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I actually did yesterday (;

Comment: It seems like there's a rather severe problem with this answer, it seems to always set `result` to a falsey value, regardless of whether `variable` is cache or not. I tested this in both CMake 3.13 and CMake 3.16. I think you meant `get_property(result CACHE variable PROPERTY TYPE)`? If I omit the `${}` around `variable` it works perfectly.

Comment: @jrh The code from my answer is intended to be used inside `foreach` loop in the question. In this context, you have to dereference `variable` to actually get a property name.

Comment: Hm... fair point, thanks. I think it would be helpful to have another example that's meant for use outside of a for loop too, I might type something up.

Answer (score 12):

Since CMake 3.14, `if (DEFINED CACHE{var})` is available.
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html

```
    set(var1 "not cached")
    if (DEFINED CACHE{var1})
        message("var1 is cache")
    else()
        message("var1 is not cache")
    endif()

    set(var2 "cached" CACHE INTERNAL "doc")
    if (DEFINED CACHE{var2})
        message("var2 is cache")
    else()
        message("var2 is not cache")
    endif()
```